# How to accept an Integer from user and get the output

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

PL/SQL anonymous block that accepts an integer n and then loop according to the input

Comment: I don't think that's possible without making an interface that communicates with the database... But, time and time again computers have proved me wrong.

Comment: A PL/SQL block cannot interact with a user. It executes on the server. You need your client to interact with the user and embed thier input into the block before it is executed. If you are using SQL Developer, look up "substitution variables".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in SQL*Developer :

```
DECLARE

  l_number_of_loops      NUMBER := &1 ;

BEGIN

  FOR i IN 1..l_number_of_loops LOOP

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Loop number : '||i) ;

  END LOOP ;


END ;
```